# SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument in multiple filter elements query

Tags: python, django, filter

Keep getting below error.

```
File "/app/community/views.py", line 643
app_1  |     (Q(roster_id=rid) | Q(roster__parent_id=rid)), 
app_1  |     ^
app_1  | SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

In this line of code inside a view (views.py).

```
CommunityRosterMembers.objects.filter(
        community_id=cid, 
        (Q(roster_id=rid) | Q(roster__parent_id=rid)), 
        (Q(rsvp_vote=1) | Q(rsvp_vote=2))
        )
```

The model I am using is:

```
class CommunityRosterMembers(models.Model):
    community = models.ForeignKey('Community', blank=False, null=False, related_name='community_roster_member_ref_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    roster = models.ForeignKey('roster.Roster', blank=False, null=False, related_name='roster_community_member_ref_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    flag = models.ForeignKey('CommunityRosterFlags', blank=False, null=False, related_name='community_roster_flag_ref_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member = models.ForeignKey('members.MemberInfo', blank=False, null=False, related_name='community_member_roster_ref_set1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    request_by = models.ForeignKey('members.MemberInfo', blank=True, null=True, related_name='community_requester_roster_ref_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_rsvp_requested = models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    date_rsvp_response = models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    rsvp_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False)#0 - Pending, 1 - Accepted, 2 - Maybe, 3 - Declined
    attendance = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False)#0 - Pending, 1 - Attended, 2 - Absent, 3 - Missed

    def __str__(self):
        return self.roster.title
```

Comment: Put `community_id=cid` as the last argument.

Comment: Now I get _Related Field got invalid lookup: eq_ error